# Questions on the difference between "you can do it the same way as she does" and "As she does, you can do it the same way"?

Tags: sentence-construction

1. Can I change this sentence **"you can do it the same way as she does"** as **"As she does, you can do it the same way"**?
2. What is the difference in meaning between them?
3. I just got an answer that both are grammatically correct, but the latter just sounds old-fashioned, so people wouldn't normally write that way. Is this answer really right? and I have no idea why the latter sounds old-fashioned unlike the former. Can you explain it?

Comment: What do you mean you *just got an answer*? From whom? (The latter sounds more unusual than old-fashioned to me. To really seem old fashioned, I would simply use *as she does, so may you*, dispensing with the rest of the words. It's the *as she does* introductory clause that leads toward an old-fashioned construction.)

Comment: @JasonBassford From a native speaker. So I asked him why. But he hasn't answered me till now.